# Como enviar vários valores com inputs de mesmo nome

Tags: php, html

O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela html que é preenchida dentro de um while numa consulta ao BD, nessa tabela alguns campos são inputs e eu preciso inserir os dados digitados nesse input no meu BD.

Estava pensando em recebe-los em um outro arquivo php por POST, só que dessa forma como os `names` são iguais acho que não iria dar muito certo.

Não sei se consegui explicar direito, mas vou deixar o código:

```
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($notas, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $cpfAluno = $linha["Aluno_CPF"];

    $pegaNomeAluno = "SELECT Nome FROM aluno WHERE CPF = '$cpfAluno' ORDER BY Nome";
    $nomeAluno = mysqli_query($con, $pegaNomeAluno); 
    $alunoArray = mysqli_fetch_array($nomeAluno, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $aluno = implode(', ', (array)$alunoArray); 

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $aluno;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<input id='prova1'  maxlength='2' size='1' name='prova1' class='form-control'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<input id='prova2'  maxlength='2' size='1' name='prova2' class='form-control'>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<input id='media'  maxlength='2' size='1' name='media' class='form-control'>";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Você quer salvar uma linha de cada vez ? ou a tabela inteira?

Comment: bom pra ser sincero não sei qual diferença faria adicionando tudo de uma vez ou linha por linha, mas eu quero adicionar todas as linhas que forem retornadas nesse while no meu banco. Exemplo se existir 10 alunos na turma serão criadas 10 linhas pelo while, cada linha será um novo registro no banco, esses registros serão feitos quando clicar em um botão para enviar

Comment: Diferença seria na forma de pegar os objetos e salvar, através de que maneira você quer ineragir com o banco, se cada linha teria um botão de salvar, ou se teria um botão "salvar" pra salvar todos os dados da tabela.
Caso seja a segunda opção , eu indicaria organizar os objetos em função javascript pegando os elementos do DOM e enviar os objetos pro php. Se for dessa forma , posso postar  um codigo de exemplo de como pegar esses elementos.

Comment: É da segunda forma que você falou, um botão para todos os dados, por favor poste o código, estou aprendendo ainda e sei muito pouco sobre javascript

Comment: Caso não consiga resolver comente na resposta, caso consiga , marque como resolvida .

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar vários campos com o mesmo nome, basta tratá-los como um array. Para isso, coloque colchetes na frente do name.

Veja

```
while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($notas, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $cpfAluno = $linha["Aluno_CPF"];

    $pegaNomeAluno = "SELECT Id, Nome FROM aluno WHERE CPF = '$cpfAluno' ORDER BY Nome";
    $nomeAluno = mysqli_query($con, $pegaNomeAluno); 
    $alunoArray = mysqli_fetch_array($nomeAluno, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $aluno = implode(', ', (array)$alunoArray); 

    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo $aluno;
            echo '<input type="hidden" id="aluno_id_' . $aluno['id'] . '" value="' . $aluno['id'] . '" name="aluno_id[]" class="form-control">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo '<input type="text" id="prova1_' . $aluno['id'] . '"  maxlength="2" size="1" name="prova1[' . $aluno['id'] . ']" class="form-control">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo '<input type="text" id="prova2_' . $aluno['id'] . '"  maxlength="2" size="1" name="prova2[' . $aluno['id'] . ']" class="form-control">';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
            echo '<input type="text" id="media_' . $aluno['id'] . '"  maxlength="2" size="1" name="media[' . $aluno['id'] . ']" class="form-control">';
        echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Observe que coloquei no name colchetes preenchidos com o id do aluno (`name="media[' . $aluno['id'] . ']"`) e coloquei tambem no ID da tag HTML para evitar que exista ID duplicados e quebre a regra do HTML que caso isso aconteça deixa o código inválido.

Adicionei também os tipos de campo, `text` e `hidden`. Não especificá-los alem de invalidar, deixa o código menos legível.

O campo `hidden` eu adicionei para facilitar o tatamento dos dados ao inserir no banco de dados. E para recuperar e tratar os dados recebidos, faça:

```
$alunoId = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aluno_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$prova1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prova1', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$prova2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prova2', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$media = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'media', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
foreach ( $alunoId as $id ) {
    $prova1[$id]; // Recupera o valor de "prova1" do aluno com o id na váriável $id
    $prova2[$id]; // Recupera o valor de "prova2" do aluno com o id na váriável $id
    $media[$id]; // Recupera o valor de "media" do aluno com o id na váriável $id
    // Faça a lógica do banco de dados aqui.
}
```

Para recuperar as variáveis recebidas via post, utilizei a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) para garantir um pouco mais de segurança para a aplicação, porem caso não importe para você, poderá usar a variável global `$_POST` sem problemas, só tenha em mente que não é a maneira mais correta de se fazer.

Answer (score -1):

> Exemplo de Solução

Aqui apresento uma maneira de fazer utilizando os elementos do DOM com javascript. Repare que armazenei esses dados em um vetor bidimensional onde cada posição é um registro de aluno.

```
[ 
   [
      "nome","nota1","nota2"
   ]

]
```

Após armazenado os dados dessa maneira, é só fazer fazer uma chamada a um arquivo php pra inserir os dados no banco. Indico utilizar Jquery para fazer essa chamada.

Relembrando que isso é apenas um **exemplo** que pode te ajudar na solução do problema.

> Veja funcionado aqui.

```js
function getObjetos(){
var table = document.getElementById('table');
debugger;
var results = [];
for(var i =0 ; i < table.children.length ;i++){

  if(table.children[i].tagName == 'TBODY'){
    var tbody = table.children[i];
    for(var c =0;  c< tbody.children.length ; c++){
      if(tbody.children[c].nodeName=='TR'){
        var tr = tbody.children[c];
        var nome = tr.children[0].textContent;
        var n1 = tr.children[1].children[0].value;
        var n2 = tr.children[2].children[0].value;
        results.push( [nome,n1,n2]);
        
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="notas">
<table border="1" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Nota1</th>
      <th>Nota2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Marcos</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nota2" id="nota1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nota2" id="nota2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alexandre</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nota2" id="nota1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nota2" id="nota2" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="salvar" onclick="getObjetos()"/>
</form>
```

Para fazer a **chamada pro seu arquivo php** e fazer as operações de banco , veja esse tutorial [aqui](http://www.devfuria.com.br/javascript/ajax-php-jquery/)

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer coisa poste aqui.